# stats.ttest_ind: extract df value

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, t-test

I am using stats.ttest_ind:

```
a = list(range(0, 10))
b = list(range(20, 40, 2))
out = stats.ttest_ind(a, b)
print(out)

#Output
TtestResult(statistic=-11.443934479174386, pvalue=1.0790209865144616e-09, df=18.0)
```

I can extract statistic and pvalue using `out[0]` and `out[1]`, but when I try to extract df with `out[2]`, I get the following error:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range.
```

`out[-1]` also does not work.

I have also tried the following code:

```
t_stat, pvalue, df = stats.ttest_ind(a,b)
```

but this resulted in the following error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

It seems as if the df value is not in `out` as soon as I try to extract it. out has length 2 and I can only get the first 2 elements.
Does anyone know what happens here or how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`out` is a `scipy.stats._stats_py.TtestResult` object.

You can fetch degrees of freedom by:

```
out.df
#18.0
```

If you do:

```
list(out)
```

you get:

```
[-11.443934479174386, 1.0790209865144618e-09]
```

So, `out[2]` and `out[-1]` will not give df.

Comment: This worked, thank you! Do you know why df is not in the list when doing `list(out)`?

Comment: You're welcome! Actually, `out` is not a list or tuple. It is a `scipy.stats._stats_py.TtestResult` object. So `list(out)` or `tuple(out)` will not work as we assume. We can also get the values by `out.statistic` and `out.pvalue`. You can read about it in the document https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html#scipy-stats-ttest-ind

Comment: @MaaikevR The `ttest_ind()` function used to return two values. The SciPy developers wanted to add the df field to the return value, but they didn't want to break backwards compatibility. There was already code that looked like `statistic, pvalue = stats.ttest_ind(a, b)`. To add this feature without breaking existing code, they couldn't just add one field to the return value. Instead, they created an object that shows only the statistic and pvalue when used as a list, but shows the extra field if accessed as `out.df`.